# Counting the number of faces of non-connected planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I have a non-connected planar graph with 15 vertices, 20 edges and 3 components. I know the Euler's formula for counting the number of faces in a connected graph, but how do I modify it using the number of components?

Comment: Hint: use Euler's formula to count the number of faces "inside" a connected graph (i.e., every face but one, the outside face), then sum these up per connected component to get the total number of inside faces of a non-connected graph.

Comment: Hint 2. If $G_i$ is a connected component of $G$, $e_i$, $v_i$, $f_i$ number of vertices, edges, and faces of $G_i$, then $v_i-e_i+f_i=2$ ($i=1,2,3$). Sum these three equations and note that some faces are counted twice.

Comment: Think of the three components embedded side by side in the plane. Then you can connect them with two additional edges, such that the number of vertices and faces does not change. Then you can use Eulers formula on the resulting connected graph. This procedure will in general give a variant of Eulers formula for nonconnected planar graphs

Comment: My favorite proof of Euler's formula is to start off with just the vertices, so there are $V$ vertices, $V$ components, $0$ edges, and $1$ face. Now start adding edges. Each added edge will either decrease the number of components by $1$ or increase the number of faces by $1$, but never both.